# How is "as...as" to be Expressed in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, idiom, syntax

In expressions e.g. "A change is as good as a rest."; "He was as good as his word."; how is the "as...as" part to be translated?

I've found *quid sicut bonum* ("Word Hippo"--not the most reliable of sources.) = "as good as".

Among the offered definitions of *sicut*: "just as"; "in the same way as"; "just as for instance" (Oxford) just about fit.

There does not appear to be a formula for "as...as".

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most common choice is the pair *tam…quam*.
For example:

> *Es tam altus quam Marcus.*
> You are as tall as Marcus.

Comment: Ørberg introduces this fairly early on in LLPSI. I found it to be fairly easy to grasp as an English speaker, particularly when he would use the word order of _X (non) tam est quam Y_.

Comment: @Adam: Interesting: we look for things and look for things...I've never seen "tamquam" written as two words before. I recall trying to translate "prius" & "quam" as two words when, of course, it was the one word, "priusquam"!

Comment: @tony Usually it doesn't really matter whether you spell pairs together or separate. For example *quare = qua re*.

Comment: @Joonas llmavirta: I was so frustrated that I recall the sentence: "neque prius fugere destiterunt quam ad flumen. = "They did not abandon to flight until they had reached the river." And "quam" = "how" or "than" did not fit in. Easy when the penny drops.