# Shorter translation of "As above, so below"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, sentence-translation

The phrase [As above, so below](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As_above,_so_below) was first attested in Arabic, and has a medieval Latin translation:

> Quod est superius est sicut quod inferius, et quod inferius est sicut quod est superius.

> That which is above is like to that which is below, and that which is below is like to that which is above.

While a very literal translation, I find this lengthy and it loses the charm of the shortened English phrase. I could shorten to just the first half of the sentence, but I feel this could be made even shorter. Is there a way to say this in a more succinct way in Classical Latin?

Edit: There is an additional translation given by Hugo of Santalia in the Wikipedia entry listed above:

> Superiora de inferioribus, inferiora de superioribus

I would still like to know if there's an even more succinct way to say this, or if it would be different in Classical Latin.

Answer (score 13):

The phrase you are looking for is either of these:

> Ut supra, sic infra.
>
> Ut supra, ita infra.

They both mean the same thing. I think the first one sounds better.

I just searched a bit for these on Google Books and was surprised not to find many hits. I thought I'd first encountered this phrase in descriptions of the medieval worldview, as a well known way to summarize it. I thought I'd encountered it numerous times, actually. Maybe it's not as well known as I thought.

Comment: I was expecting to find more readily available translations as well, although to be fair I didn't Google that hard after reading the Wikipedia entry.

Answer (score 6):

As...so... can be represented in a few ways, but I like [tam...quam...](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dtam) for it:

- *tam de superiis, quam de inferiis.*
- Just as from above, so too from below.

This also gets to the Arabic better, if the Wikipedia article is accurate.

Comment: It was actually @tony's post about [as...as](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/15655/how-is-as-as-to-be-expressed-in-latin) and the answer to that which got me thinking about this phrase. I wasn't sure if _tam...quam_ could be used like this so I left it out of my question. It's great that it more closely parallels the original Arabic!

Comment: @Adam I should note that the *de* is what the Arabic has that the original Latin doesn't. What *comes from above...*. That said, I'm relying on Wikipedia for that information, as I don't know Arabic.

Comment: @C.M.Weimer The "من" of the Arabic does indeed have a basic meaning of "from" (though it can have other meanings too).